# Google Api via PHP : Get user profile

Tags: php, google-api

I have added website login via Google API (using google php api client), what I am not sure is how I get the user profile.

The code to get authenticate is:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId(ClientIDGoesHere);
$client->setClientSecret(ClientSecretGoesHere);
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_READONLY);

$redirectUrl = 'http://AReference.ngrok.io/performGoogleLogin.php';
$client->setRedirectUri($redirectUrl);

$oauth = $client->getOAuth2Service();
```

I tried the following from [this website](https://www.codexworld.com/login-with-google-api-using-php/), but it says userinfo isn't found:

```
$userProfile = $oauth->userinfo->get();
```

I get the following error:
Notice: Undefined property: Google\Auth\OAuth2::$userinfo in googleLogin.php on line 23

I am after given_name, family_name, email, gender, picture (nice to have)

Comment: please show us the _exact_ error message you're getting

Comment: I have edited the question to add the error message.  Thank you

Comment: Ok thanks. Perhaps you're using a different version of the Google PHP library then. Or possibly because you don't appear to have authenticated yet. Have you omitted some code from this example?

Comment: This is the latest version from Google's Github page

Comment: Did you fix the issue? I am having exact same problem 

Comment: @user9156598 You need to ensure that you are setting the Google API token before you access the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP and @user9156598, this is the solution that worked for me.

```
$oauth = new Google_Service_Oauth2($googleClient->GetClient());
$userProfile = $oauth->userinfo->get();
$output = "<p>Name: " .  $userProfile['name'] . '</p>';
$output = $output . "<p>Family Name: " .  $userProfile['familyName'] . '</p>';
$output = $output . "<p>Given Name: " .  $userProfile['givenName'] . '</p>';
$output = $output . "<p>Gender: " .  $userProfile['gender'] . '</p>';
$output = $output . "<p>Email Address: " .  $userProfile['email'] . '</p>';
$output = $output . "<p>Verified Email Address: " .  $userProfile['verifiedEmail'] . '</p>';
$output = $output . "<p>Picture: " .  $userProfile['picture'] . '</p>';
print($output);
```

Google client constructor:

```
    $this->m_client = new Google_Client();
    $this->m_client->setApplicationName("Local Social Meetups");
    $this->m_client->setClientId(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);
    $this->m_client->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET);

    $this->m_client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
    $this->m_client->setAccessType('offline');
    $this->m_client->setApprovalPrompt("force");
    $this->m_client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);

    // Set the scope of information that the application has access to.  In
    // this case it's just the users profile.
    $scopes = array(
        Google_Service_Oauth2::USERINFO_PROFILE,
        Google_Service_Oauth2::USERINFO_EMAIL
    );
    $this->m_client->setScopes($scopes);

    // The redirection Url that is used by Google after authentication.
    $this->m_client->setRedirectUri(GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URL);

    if (isset($_SESSION['googleAccessToken']))
    {
        $this->m_client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['googleAccessToken']);
    }

    $this->m_oauth = $this->m_client->getOAuth2Service();
```